# How to write a function with linkedhashmap parameter

Tags: java, jsp, linkedhashmap

Sorry i'm new to linkedhashmap, i have no idea how to apply for this. Appreciated for any help.

### JSP file

```
<%
    LinkedHashMap htItem    = (LinkedHashMap) session.getAttribute("RiskItem");
    Vector Record           = new Vector();
           Record           = common.record(htItem); // i want to bring htrisk to record.java
%>
```

### Record Java file

```
public Vector record(htItem) // how should i write in my parameter? 
{
    //data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a type to the argument (If I understand your question correctly)

```
public Vector record(LinkedHashMap htItem) // Type provided here 
{
    // code
}
```

Also, I don't get what the `common` variable does.  I believe it's the instance of class `Record`.  Please edit your question if so.

Comment: I did this, but get error message. "LinkedHashMap" cannot be resolved (or this is not valid type) for the argument htItem of the method record"

Comment: You might need to import it.  e.g. `import java.util.LinkedHashMap`

Comment: common is a java file name. which i will called a method record.

Comment: Ok, sorry I am not able to understand what exactly you are looking for.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: same, have error message. "The import java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be resolved". is it related to java compliance level ?

Comment: I don't think there is any compliance issue here.  Where are you getting this error?  In your JSP compilation or the `common` class?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I wanted to pass a LinkedHashMap(String, LinkedHashMap) as a parameter. In the function, define the complete signature of your LinkedHashMap like:

```
public Vector record(LinkedHashMap<insert key, value> hitem)
```

It should work properly now. Also, don't forget to import LinkedList from java.util.